# Using WebClient to propagate request headers received in a Spring Webflux applications to downstream services

Tags: spring, spring-webflux, opentracing, spring-webclient

I have two kinds of Webflux applications, annotation-based and route-based. These applications are called with a set of headers, some of which (Open Tracing) I need to propagate in downstream calls using `WebClient`.

If these were normal Spring WebMvc applications I would use a Filter to keep the selected headers in a `ThreadLocal`, access it in a `RestTemplate` interceptor to send them to subsequent services and clear the `ThreadLocal`.

What's the proper way to replicate this behaviour in WebFlux applications?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I solved it using Project Reactor's Context to store the headers in a WebFilter. Then they are gotten in the WebClient's ExchangeFilterFunction. Here's the whole solution:

**WebFilter**

```
class OpenTracingFilter(private val openTracingHeaders: Set<String>) : WebFilter {

    private val logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(javaClass)

    override fun filter(exchange: ServerWebExchange, chain: WebFilterChain): Mono<Void> {

        return chain.filter(exchange)
                .subscriberContext { ctx ->
                    var updatedContext = ctx
                    exchange.request.headers.forEach {
                        if (openTracingHeaders.contains(it.key.toLowerCase())) {
                            logger.debug("Found OpenTracing Header - key {} - value {}", it.key, it.value[0])
                            updatedContext = updatedContext.put(it.key, it.value[0])
                        }
                    }
                    updatedContext
                }
    }
}
```

**OpenTracingExchangeFilterFunction**

```
class OpenTracingExchangeFilterFunction(private val headers: Set<String>) : ExchangeFilterFunction {

    private val logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(javaClass)

    override fun filter(request: ClientRequest, next: ExchangeFunction): Mono<ClientResponse> {

        logger.debug("OpenTracingExchangeFilterFunction - filter()")
        return OpenTracingClientResponseMono(request, next, headers)
    }
}
```

**OpenTracingClientResponseMono**

```
class OpenTracingClientResponseMono(private val request: ClientRequest,
                                    private val next: ExchangeFunction,
                                    private val headersToPropagate: Set<String>) : Mono<ClientResponse>() {

    private val logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(javaClass)

    override fun subscribe(subscriber: CoreSubscriber<in ClientResponse>) {
        val context = subscriber.currentContext()

        val requestBuilder = ClientRequest.from(request)
        requestBuilder.headers { httpHeaders ->
            headersToPropagate.forEach {
                if(context.hasKey(it)) {
                    logger.debug("Propagating header key {} - value{}", it, context.get<String>(it))
                    httpHeaders[it] = context.get<String>(it)
                }
            }
        }
        val mutatedRequest = requestBuilder.build()
        next.exchange(mutatedRequest).subscribe(subscriber)
    }


}
```

**OpenTracingConfiguration**

```
@Configuration
class OpenTracingConfiguration(private val openTracingConfigurationProperties: OpenTracingConfigurationProperties) {

    @Bean
    fun webClient(): WebClient {
        return WebClient.builder().filter(openTracingExchangeFilterFunction()).build()
    }

    @Bean
    fun openTracingFilter(): WebFilter {
        return OpenTracingFilter(openTracingConfigurationProperties.headers)
    }

    @Bean
    fun openTracingExchangeFilterFunction(): OpenTracingExchangeFilterFunction {
        return OpenTracingExchangeFilterFunction(openTracingConfigurationProperties.headers)
    }
}
```

**OpenTracingConfigurationProperties**

```
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties("opentracing")
class OpenTracingConfigurationProperties {

    lateinit var headers: Set<String>

}
```

**application.yml**

```
opentracing:
  headers:
    - x-request-id
    - x-b3-traceid
    - x-b3-spanid
    - x-b3-parentspanid
    - x-b3-sampled
    - x-b3-flags
    - x-ot-span-context
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the response, but I don't understand the `XxxMono` class, what does that implement?

Comment: Which XxxMono class?

Comment: Sorry I mean `OpenTracingClientResponseMono`. What methods it should implement to get access to the context?

Comment: The purpuse of that class is access the current context to locate the headers from the original request and propagate them mutating the WebClient's request

Comment: It has to extend `Mono<ClientResponse>()` and implement `subscribe(subscriber: CoreSubscriber<in ClientResponse>)` -> https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html#subscribe-reactor.core.CoreSubscriber-

Comment: Thanks! Now I understand.

Answer (score 2):

I needed to pass x-request-id header to a downstream service in my application. Achieved this by   adding `WebFilter` that writes x-request-id to a reactor context

```
class ContextWebFilter : WebFilter {
    override fun filter(exchange: ServerWebExchange, chain: WebFilterChain): Mono<Void> {
        val headers = exchange.request.headers

        val xRequestId = headers[X_REQUEST_ID]?.firstOrNull() ?: ""
        val requestId = xRequestId.ifBlank { UUID.randomUUID().toString() }       

        return chain
            .filter(exchange)
            .contextWrite { it.put(X_REQUEST_ID, requestId) }
    }

    companion object {
        const val X_REQUEST_ID = "X-REQUEST-ID"
    }
}
```

and updating `WebClient` with `ExchangeFilterFunction` that updates outgoing request

```
WebClient.builder()
        .filter(
            ExchangeFilterFunction.ofRequestProcessor { request ->
                Mono.deferContextual { context ->
                    val xRId = context.getOrDefault<String>("X-REQUEST-ID", "")
                    logger.debug("Set X-REQUEST-ID={} as a header to outgoing call", xRId)
                    Mono.just(
                        ClientRequest.from(request)
                            .header("X-REQUEST-ID", xRId)
                            .build()
                    )
                }
            }
        )
        .baseUrl("http://localhost:8080")
        .build()
```